# Android Compose: draw transparent circle on image

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an image and I want to draw dark rectangle over it with a transparent circle, so the result will be something like this:
[image: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F36763696%2Fhow-to-create-a-transparent-circle-inside-rectangle-shape-in-xml-in-android&psig=AOvVaw18ZjvY-j8QyYzFw1xsmOdJ&ust=1630768957499000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCPD1mveN4_ICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE]

I have ended up with this code:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RectangleShape)
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Black)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
                scale *= zoom
            }
        }) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.Center)
                .graphicsLayer(
                    scaleX = maxOf(.2f, minOf(5f, scale)),
                    scaleY = maxOf(.2f, minOf(5f, scale))
                ),
            bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = null
        )
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), onDraw = {
            drawRect(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))
            drawCircle(
                Color.Transparent,
                style = Fill,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
        })
    }
```

But it seems like it just draws a dark circle on top of the image instead of clearing darken rectangle...

*It would be also super handy if you would suggest how to crop image based on this circle coordinates.*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can to use [`clipPath`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/drawscope/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope).clipPath(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.ClipOp,kotlin.Function1)) with `clipOp = ClipOp.Difference` option:

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    val circlePath = Path().apply {
        addOval(Rect(center, size.minDimension / 2))
    }
    clipPath(circlePath, clipOp = ClipOp.Difference) {
        drawRect(SolidColor(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f)))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to necessarily use `clipPath`, you can use Porterduff(BlendMode) modes too, which is actually preferred way when you check sample codes or [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947835/android-canvas-draw-transparent-circle-on-image) for clearing or removing some pixels or manipulating pixels.

It only requires small modifications to your code to work, you can check my answer how to apply Porterduff modes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69790654/5457853).

1- adding graphics layer with **alpha less than 1f**

```
.graphicsLayer {
    alpha = .99f
}
```

will fix the issue.

Full implementation

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Black)
        .fillMaxSize()
) {

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        contentDescription = null
    )
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            // ONLY ADD THIS
            .graphicsLayer {
                alpha = .99f
            }
    ) {

        // Destination
        drawRect(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))

        // Source
        drawCircle(
            color = Color.Transparent,
            blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
        )

    }
}
```

2- Saving to a layer

```
with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
    val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

    // Destination
    drawRect(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))

    // Source
    drawCircle(
        color = Color.Transparent,
        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
    )
    restoreToCount(checkPoint)
}
```

Full Implementation

```
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
            val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

            // Destination
            drawRect(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))

            // Source
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Transparent,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
            restoreToCount(checkPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Also you can check [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials#6-2-blendporter-duff-modes) to get familiar with BlendModes, path operations and more about canvas.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to actually use this transparent circle to do a crop of an image

Answer (score 0):

You have to change composition strategy to make it work. As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/graphics/draw/modifiers#compositing-strategy-offscreen):

> If you didn't use CompositingStrategy.Offscreen, the results of applying BlendMode.Clear clears all the pixels in the destination, regardless of what was already set– leaving the window’s rendering buffer (black) visible.

So just add this to Canvas modifier:

```
 .graphicsLayer {
       compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
  }
```

And the whole code will look like this:

```
Box(modifier = Modifier
    .clip(RectangleShape)
    .fillMaxSize()
    .background(Color.Black)
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
            scale *= zoom
        }
    }) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.Center)
            .graphicsLayer(
                scaleX = maxOf(.2f, minOf(5f, scale)),
                scaleY = maxOf(.2f, minOf(5f, scale))
            ),
        bitmap = bitmap.asImageBitmap(),
        contentDescription = null
    )
    Canvas(
      modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .graphicsLayer {
            compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen
       }, 
      onDraw = {
        drawRect(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f))
        drawCircle(
            Color.Transparent,
            style = Fill,
            blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
        )
    })
}
```