# Android Compose - Apply PorterDuffMode to image with overlaping shape with same color and alpha

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'd like to achieve this design (Both arrow and oval should have the same color)

[image]

I achieved this by stacking two Box

```
@Composable
private fun Pin() {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .background(
                    color = pinColor,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 100.dp)
                )
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(6.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            ) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                    painter = icon.painter,
                )
                Text(
                    text = "2",
                    modifier = modifier.padding(start = 2.dp, end = 2.dp)
                )
            }
        }
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
                .size(
                    width = 12.dp,
                    height = 8.dp
                )
                .offset(y = - 4.dp)
                .clip(shape = TriangleShape())
                .background(color = pinColor)
        )
    }
}
```

The result is this. Since backgrounds has alpha, the overlaping part blend the colors.

[image]

I managed to fix this by adding `graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)` to the Trianagle from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65653560/jetpack-compose-applying-porterduffmode-to-image). The problem is now there is a line visible distinguishing the two boxes.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer(alpha = 0.99f)
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        .size(
            width = 12.dp,
            height = 8.dp
        )
        .offset(y = - 4.dp)
        .clip(shape = TriangleShape())
        .background(color = pinColor)
)
```

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to achieve the same result without seeing the line between the two boxes? Could using Canvas be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both bubble and arrow has alpha in it you need to remove the intersection of them then draw arrow outside of offscreen buffer.

To apply blend modes you can create buffer as, you can't use alpha or `compositionStrategy = CompositionStrategy.Offscreen` because we only want to remove intersection from bubble.

```
with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
    val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)
    // We will draw here
    restoreToCount(checkPoint)
}
```

Created a custom shape with

```
val triangleShape = remember {
    GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
        moveTo(0f, 0f)
        lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height)
        lineTo(size.width, 0f)
        lineTo(0f, 0f)
    }
}

val density = LocalDensity.current
val color = Color.LightGray.copy(alpha = .5f)
val offsetDp = 40.dp
```

Draw arrow as

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(2.dp, Color.Red)
        .padding(bottom = offsetDp / 2)
        .drawWithCache {

            val outline = triangleShape.createOutline(
                size = Size(40.dp.toPx(), 40.dp.toPx()),
                layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                density = density
            )

            val offset = offsetDp.toPx()

            onDrawWithContent {

                with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                    val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)
                    // Destination
                    drawContent()

                    // Source
                    translate(
                        left = (size.width - outline.bounds.size.width) / 2,
                        top = size.height - offset / 2
                    ) {
                        drawOutline(
                            outline = outline,
                            color = color,
//                                    blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                        )
                    }
                    restoreToCount(checkPoint)
                }

//                        translate(
//                            left = (size.width - outline.bounds.size.width) / 2,
//                        top = size.height - offset / 2
//                        ) {
//                            drawOutline(
//                                outline = outline,
//                                color = color
//                            )
//                        }
            }
        }
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(color, RoundedCornerShape(45)),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text("Bubble Content", color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

When you draw it like this result will be

[image]

Now uncomment `blendMode = BlendMode.Clear`

[image]

In image above intersection of both are removed. Last part is to draw arrow again while intersection of 2 are removed. Uncomment second draw to draw both of them without alpha blending.

[image]

If you have artifacts at the edges due to alpha you can draw another one with 1px bigger with `BlendMode.DstAtop`

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Test() {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {


        val triangleShape = remember {
            GenericShape { size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection ->
                moveTo(0f, 0f)
                lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height)
                lineTo(size.width, 0f)
                lineTo(0f, 0f)

            }
        }

        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val color = Color.Black
        val offsetDp = 40.dp


        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = offsetDp / 2)


                .drawWithCache {

                    val outline = triangleShape.createOutline(
                        size = Size(40.dp.toPx(), 40.dp.toPx()),
                        layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                        density = density
                    )

                    val outline2 = triangleShape.createOutline(
                        size = Size(40.dp.toPx()+2, 40.dp.toPx()+2),
                        layoutDirection = layoutDirection,
                        density = density
                    )


                    val offset = offsetDp.toPx()

                    onDrawWithContent {

                        with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                            val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                            // Destination
                            drawContent()

                            // Source
                            translate(
                                left = (size.width - outline.bounds.size.width) / 2,
                                top = size.height - offset / 2
                            ) {
                                drawOutline(
                                    outline = outline,
                                    color = color.copy(alpha = 1f),
                                    blendMode = BlendMode.DstOut
                                )
                            }

                            // Draw this behind destination
                            translate(
                                left = (size.width - outline2.bounds.size.width) / 2,
                                top = size.height - offset / 2
                            ) {
                                drawOutline(
                                    outline = outline2,
                                    color = color,
                                    blendMode = BlendMode.DstAtop
                                )
                            }
                            restoreToCount(checkPoint)
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.size(100.dp).background(color, RoundedCornerShape(45)),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("Bubble Content", color = Color.White)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: This looks great! but then when I use a black background it seems there is an elavation? Look at the black bubble https://ibb.co/k5NjN9V

Comment: This happens probably because of outline, if you draw with path i don't think this will happen. I tested without blend mode and setting first triangle's color to Green and i can see green 1px below. Blend mode works fine as it seems but outline leaves 1 px space even if you draw it twice with different colors

Comment: @MehdiSatei updated answer for artifact prevention near edges

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This worked flawlessly for me.

Comment: @Thracian Couldn't we just have used single path for this shape?

Comment: @VivekGupta If the shape is Rectangle or Rounded rectangle you can, if it's a circle or some image difficult to compute intersection you can use BlendModes. As you can see both image have alpha less than 1f, when they intersect their alpha values are added. Because of that we need to do these operations.

Comment: okay fair point, but we can find the intersection point using maths. Lemme try and post :)

Comment: @VivekGupta sure, also question's title is `Apply PorterDuffMode to image with overlaping shape with same color and alpha` this alpha blending has an issue. And been a good practice for me to solve it. Which you can come across with some complex alpha blending sample

Comment: well, then my answer wouldn't be right as per question title.

Comment: @Thracian i achieved the required shape :) computation of intersection point on a ellipse is straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired design without the line visible between the two boxes, you can use a `Canvas` to draw the arrow and oval shapes with the same color and alpha. This approach will give you more control over the drawing and help avoid any blending issues. Here's how you can do it:

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun Pin() {
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp),
        onDraw = {
            val pinColor = Color(0xFF1976D2) // Replace with your desired color

            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            // Draw the oval
            drawOval(
                color = pinColor.copy(alpha = 0.4f), // Adjust the alpha as needed
                topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f),
                size = Size(width, height)
            )

            // Draw the arrow
            val path = Path().apply {
                moveTo(width / 2f, 0f)
                lineTo(0f, height)
                lineTo(width, height)
                close()
            }

            drawPath(
                path = path,
                color = pinColor.copy(alpha = 0.4f), // Adjust the alpha as needed
                style = Stroke(0f)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

In this code, we use the `Canvas` composable to draw both the oval and the arrow shapes with the same color and alpha. The `drawOval` function is used to draw the oval, and the `drawPath` function is used to draw the arrow. The `alpha` value can be adjusted as needed to control the transparency.

This approach should give you the desired design without the visible line between the two shapes.

**# Update**

If you want to create a resizable oval container that dynamically adjusts its size based on the content (an icon and potentially text), you can achieve this in Compose without explicitly specifying a fixed size for the canvas. Instead, you can use Compose's layout system to create a resizable container.

Here's a high-level approach to create such a resizable oval container:

1. Define a Composable that represents your oval container, which can adapt its size to its content.
2. Use the `Box` Composable to create a resizable container. The `Box` allows you to overlay its children and adjust their size based on content.
3. Inside the `Box`, you can place your oval shape (using `Canvas`) and the content (icon and text) inside the oval.
4. Use the `modifier` of the `Canvas` and other Composables to apply layout and drawing logic as needed.

Here's a simplified example:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ResizableOvalContainer(icon: ImageVector, text: String) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            // Draw the oval shape here using draw functions.
        }

        // You can adjust the size of the content based on your requirements.
        Icon(imageVector = icon, contentDescription = null, modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp))
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Black,
                fontSize = 16.sp
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

In this example, the `Canvas` takes the entire available space within the `Box`. The oval's size is determined by the `Box`'s aspect ratio, and the content (icon and text) can be sized and positioned accordingly.

You can further customize the layout and appearance to match your specific requirements. This approach allows the oval container to adapt to the content's size dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! The reason why I didn't use Canvas is that the Canvas needs a fixed size. But in my case, I don't really know the size because the oval will contain an icon and could contain a text to it as well. How should I handle this?

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it serves your goal. Thank you.